# Windows damaged after corrupted linux install

Tags: linux, windows-10, linux-mint

As I was trying to install linux mint the install was interrupted, and now even though I changed the boot order from usb to hdd i still end up with a gnu grub cli, like in the photo. I have no recovery cd and I don't know how to proceed. My files are backed up, luckily.

Windows version 10, laptop is toshiba satellite.

[image: Sad conputer]

- issue was resolved as files were intact. Got lucky.

Comment: What's your version of Windows?

Comment: @LukeG. Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get on another copy of Windows 10 and see if you can use the option to "Create a System Repair Disc".  This was in Windows 8, and I'm not sitting at my Windows 10 to test it right now.  Conversely, you could get a Windows 10 install disc from a friend to borrow.

Regardless, boot up the system with either and look for the "Startup Repair" option.  It will restore Windows' Master Boot Record (MBR) and should get your system working to boot directly to Windows.

There may be other ways to boot it (e.g. Ultimate Boot CD) but I'm not sure the MBR tools there are as robust as the one on the Windows disc.